# Binding a ComboBox to an IList and using SelectedValue

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a `ComboBox` set up as follows, where `KVPList` is an `IList` (of `KeyValuePair` if it matters):

```
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
comboBox.DataSource = KVPList;
```

I then have set up a binding with `SelectedValue`, binding to a `BindingSource` (to a `DataSet`). For whatever reason, the combo box always turns up blank when the form is displayed. It is properly populated, however (the values of the `IList` show up fine and can be selected).

Now, I've tried my best to trace through, and it appears to initially set the SelectedValue correctly when bound, but then somewhere along the way it gets reset to `null`. I've played with the order things get called as well, to no avail.

Can anyone shed some light on this or suggest a workaround?

For the record, on the same form, I have another `ComboBox` on the same form, with its `SelectedValue` bound to the same `BindingSource`. The `DataSource` is a `DataSet`, not an `IList` and it works like a charm. It might be an option to make a `DataTable` from the `IList`, but it seems like a whole lot of extra overhead; I'm generating the `IList` from an enumeration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ouch. After basically half a day wasted on this one, I've figured it out. It was completely an error on my part.

The `KVPList` was set to an `IList` of `KeyValuePair<`**`short`**`,string>`, but the data field is of type **`int`**. Essentially, the databinding would fire, and set the `SelectedValue` property. Then the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` bindings would fire, checking the `SelectedValue` again. Since the `ValueMember` is of type `short`, not `int`, it wouldn't find a match and thus set it to null.

Something funny must be happening with boxing and unboxing, but I'm too tired to understand why right now.

I'll leave this question up in case someone else runs into the same issue. It's hard to track down because I would expect it to either try to cast or throw an exception, not silently go null. After all, `short` and `int` are both value types and last I checked `(int)10 == (short)10` holds true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran into the same problem. My dependency property type was IList<Foo> which was binding to an ILIst<IFoo>. (Foo implements IFoo). Everything seemed to be working except the dependency property value was always null. No exceptions or debug output. When I changed the dependency property type to IList<IFoo> everything started working.